# oozie - capture date and pass it as hive parameter

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I need to periodically load files from local file system into hdfs and update hive table partitions. The query for updating the partitions depends on the

```
timestamps(select * where date = "").
```

Could use Oozie EL but I need todays and yesterday's date.
Moreover I don't understand how to capture date and pass it as a parameter into hive script.

How do I Do this, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write a coordinator.xml and use it's date functions

```
${coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -1, 'DAY')}
```

docs here: http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.7.3._coord:nominalTime_EL_Function